Not able to read input registers via Modbus in ESP-IDF
I have a code which has different functions for reading and writing holding registers and coils and reading input registers. Of these 5 functions, the function for reading input registers is not working. According to the error message the CID declaration is wrong but it seems right. Can anybody please help me with what is wrong here?
The error I am getting:

E (449) MB_CONTROLLER_MASTER: mbc_serial_master_get_parameter: The requested cid(2) is not configured correctly. Check data dictionary for correctness.


E (459) MB_CONTROLLER_MASTER: mbc_master_get_parameter(74): Master get parameter failure, error=(0x102) (ESP_ERR_INVALID_ARG).


E (469) MASTER_TEST: Characteristic #2 (Length) read failed, err = 0x102 (ESP_ERR_INVALID_ARG).

The function call:
float test1 = master_read_input_register(2);

Read Input function and CID definition:
enum {
    CID_HOLD_DATA_0 = 0, // Unique identifier for the 'Length' parameter (for reading)
    CID_HOLD_DATA_1, // Unique identifier for the 'sending data' parameter (for writing)
    CID_INPUT_DATA_0, // Unique identifier for the 'Length' parameter in input registers
    CID_COIL_0, // Unique identifier for the coil
    CID_COUNT
};

const mb_parameter_descriptor_t device_parameters[] = {
    { CID_HOLD_DATA_0, STR("Length"), STR("cm"), 1, MB_PARAM_HOLDING, 775, 2,
        HOLD_OFFSET(holding_data0), PARAM_TYPE_FLOAT, 4, OPTS_NO_LIMIT, PAR_PERMS_READ_WRITE_TRIGGER },
    { CID_HOLD_DATA_1, STR("sending data"), STR("words.."), 1, MB_PARAM_HOLDING, 780, 2, // Same address
        HOLD_OFFSET(holding_data1), PARAM_TYPE_FLOAT, 4, OPTS_NO_LIMIT, PAR_PERMS_READ_WRITE_TRIGGER },
    { CID_INPUT_DATA_0, STR("Length"), STR("cm"), 1, MB_PARAM_INPUT, 770, 2,
        INPUT_OFFSET(input_data0), PARAM_TYPE_FLOAT, 4, OPTS_NO_LIMIT, PAR_PERMS_READ },
    { CID_COIL_0, STR("Coil_0"), STR("state"), 1, MB_PARAM_COIL, 522, 1, // Address 522, 1-bit size
        0, PARAM_TYPE_U8, 1, OPTS_NO_LIMIT, PAR_PERMS_READ_WRITE_TRIGGER }
};

//read input register
float master_read_input_register(uint16_t cid) {
    esp_err_t err = ESP_OK;
    float value = NAN; // Default to NAN to indicate an error if read fails
    const mb_parameter_descriptor_t* param_descriptor = NULL;
    bool alarm_state = false;

    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Start reading input register for CID: %u...", cid);

    // Get parameter descriptor for the provided CID
    err = mbc_master_get_cid_info(cid, &param_descriptor);

    if ((err != ESP_ERR_NOT_FOUND) && (param_descriptor != NULL) && param_descriptor->mb_param_type == MB_PARAM_INPUT) {
        void* temp_data_ptr = master_get_param_data(param_descriptor);
        assert(temp_data_ptr);

        uint8_t type = 0;
        err = mbc_master_get_parameter(cid, (char*)param_descriptor->param_key, (uint8_t*)temp_data_ptr, &type);

        if (err == ESP_OK) {
            uint16_t raw_value = *(uint16_t*)temp_data_ptr;
            ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Raw value = %u", raw_value);
            value = (float)raw_value; // Convert raw value to float
            ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Characteristic #%u %s (%s) value = %f read successfully.",
            param_descriptor->cid,
            param_descriptor->param_key,
            param_descriptor->param_units,
            value);

            // Check if value is within the expected range
            if ((value > param_descriptor->param_opts.max) || (value < param_descriptor->param_opts.min)) {
                ESP_LOGW(TAG, "Value is out of range: %f", value);
                alarm_state = true; // Set alarm if value is out of range
                return NAN; // Return NAN if the value is out of range
            }
        } else {
            ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Characteristic #%u (%s) read failed, err = 0x%x (%s).",
            param_descriptor->cid,
            param_descriptor->param_key,
            (int)err,
            (char*)esp_err_to_name(err));
        }
    } else {
        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Parameter descriptor not found or invalid type for CID: %u", cid);
    }

    if (alarm_state) {
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Alarm triggered by CID #%u.", param_descriptor->cid);
    }

    return value;
}


Looks like you have two things on the same register address - how is that supposed to work?

Yes there are 2 CID definitions for same holding register. But they both work. The problem is with input register CID definition according to the log messages. Also, I am changing the address in one of the holding register CID to prevent further confusion.

The 'STR' field in the arrays i.e. the second element in the CID definition arrays need to be different. There are two CID definitions that have the same string 'Length'. Changing one of them solved the issue.
